# Crash in Android app (Profile)

Tags: android

i have an android app .. and when i click profile it crashes and i get this report .. can you help

i dont see any errors when open profile activiy. it just keep on crashing every single time when i click on my profile or profile photo

```
    USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=7.0
APP_VERSION_NAME=2.2.5
BRAND=samsung
PHONE_MODEL=SM-G925F
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soog.aldeera.joysale/com.soog.aldeera.joysale.Profile}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.soog.aldeera.joysale-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.soog.aldeera.joysale-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.soog.aldeera.joysale.Profile.onCreate(Profile.java:83)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.soog.aldeera.joysale-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.soog.aldeera.joysale-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.soog.aldeera.joysale.Profile.onCreate(Profile.java:83)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.soog.aldeera.joysale-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.soog.aldeera.joysale-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.soog.aldeera.joysale.Profile.onCreate(Profile.java:83)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.soog.aldeera.joysale-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.soog.aldeera.joysale-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.soog.aldeera.joysale.Profile.onCreate(Profile.java:83)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: It would be more clear if you add your application code, and better to share it via github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your profile layout, you used `com.hitasoft.app.external.RoundedImageView`, this class is not there in your project.

So try to use `ImageView` or some other "`RoundedImageView`".